# Jammit deployment not working with Heroku - 500 error received

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, jammit

I have been using Jammit to handle asset packaging in a rails3 app, hosted at heroku, without any problems.

I have now added some new css and js files to my application and when I push the updates to heroku the new assets are not loading. Instead, each css and javascript file produces the standard heroku 500 error page (i.e. when i view the css/js files loaded with firefox web developer addon, I see the source code of the 500 error page).

Funny thing is that the app runs without any problems in development mode, with all the recent versions of css/js files loading independently just as they are supposed to.

Since I do not receive any error messages in development mode I am a bit lost here and do not know where to start looking - what could be the issue here.

Note: I use '[Heroku Jammit](http://www.chebyte.com/en/2010/10/05/jammit-en-heroku/)' plugin to compile the assets and deploy to heroku and the compilation finishes without any error messages. (I use the 'heroku jammit:deploy' command, then 'git add .' everything, then commit changes and push to heroku master git rep.

I could really use some help here, has anyone experienced any similar issues with Jammit and Heroku?

Many thanks for your time and help!

Kind Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

i guess, one of the reason might be that - jammit is unable to compress you js files. If you happen to have any syntax error in your js files, jammit compression fails. Try running "jammit" on local machine, and see if it fails.